# How to divide a disk to the Win10 on the Mac?

Tags: windows-10, mac

I use Boot Camp created a win10 system on my Mac 2017.

[image]

But you see the C disk only 37.8G usable （40G）, how can I divide a disk from the mac to add a D disk to the Win10 system?

Comment: Please don't cross post to multiple SE sites. Pick one & stick to it - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/294385/how-to-add-a-disk-to-the-win10-on-the-mac

Comment: @Tetsujin ok, I know that.